# Publishing an Android Library and removing access to source code

Tags: android, android-library

I am building a library for Android that houses some c/c++ code within it.

Think of it as a Java wrapper around the c/c++ code where developers interface with the Java and not the c/c++.

I want to be able to give anyone access to this library but I don't what to give them access to the source code (specifically the c/c++ code) because secrets.

Is there a typical way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AAR holds the compiled output (`.so` files), not the C/C++ source code. Hence, if you publish an AAR, you do not have to worry about shipping the C/C++ source code.

Comment: How doth one acquire this beloved AAR?

Comment: @luckyging3r: It is the standard way of creating libraries in Android: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library

Comment: The AAR is what I would give to someone (or publish) for them to load into their application and use? How do I generate the AAR file to begin with?

Comment: hah, found it `When you want to build the AAR file, select the library module in the Project window and then click Build > Build APK.`

Comment: I will look into this further. Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: @luckyging3r: For one-off distribution, that approach will work. More typically, you will distribute the AAR through a public or private artifact repository. You are already consuming AARs through such repositories, as that is where the Android Support libraries and related bits come from.